# JQuery closing dialog on document.ready

Tags: jquery, dialog

```
<div id="dialog"><img src="images/load.gif"/></div>
```

I have this gif that plays before `document.ready`, and i'm trying to close it after the page is ready. I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dialog").dialog('option', 'dialogClass', 'alert'); //show dialog modal while page is loading

$(document).ready(function() { //document is ready, close loading gif
$("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
```

This code works but it doesn't remove the loading gif, it still shows on the page. I have tried adding `$('#dialog').remove()` but this seems to 'break' my page by not letting the rest of the page execute.

how can i remove this dialog when the page is ready?

Comment: i would suggest you to rename dialog id to something more specify, like "loading"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css

```
#dialog {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#dialog").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, It is better to wait for the DOM to be loaded (and so JQuery library) before using jQuery method.

Secondly, unless you are loading content via Ajax, it is a little bit useless to show a dialog waiting box and immediately remove it (The time before the dialog creation and the dialog destruction is extremely short).

Moreover, the dialog function, used with destroy, **do not** remove the original HTML code. It only remove all modifications made by the dialog plugin during the dialog creation.

So, when you apply the

```
$("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
```

You only remove the dialog HTML structure that is wrapped aroud the

```
<div id="dialog"><img src="images/load.gif"/></div>
```

But not the DIV it self.

In my point of view, the best way is to add your spinner with classic HTML and CSS, And when the page is loaded and jQuery loaded, wait a bit and then remove it.

You could have this piece of CSS

```
#dialog
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

and this piece of Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Wait a short delay, animate opacity and finally remove
    $("#dialog").delay(300).animate({
        "opacity" : 0
    }, 500, function() {
        $("#dialog").remove();
    });

});
```

good luck

Comment: the #dialog not need position absolute and other stuff, jquery-ui doing it itself, just need to be initial div hidden, that will help

Comment: If you read well, I advice to do not use jQuery-ui dialog before the DOM Content loaded event, juste simple HTML and CSS. It is safer and fasterregarding loaded JS like jQuery.

Comment: best is to advice do not use javascript at all in that case... hm, i have idea - in standalone css make the rules that draw dialog, in html at top show div with dialog, in the end of html make css definition that define something like `#loading {display:none;}`